# How to scale an Android xml layout while keeping its XML properties?

Tags: android, xml, border, scale, android-framelayout

I've got a framelayout with a 2 pixel border. In the corner of the framelayout, there's a button that the user can drag to resize the layout. I'm doing the resizing by listening to onTouch and calling setScale on the framelayout.

The problem I'm having is that the border and button get skewed when I call setScale on the layout. Is there a way to achieve this resizing effect while keeping the border at 2 pixels and the button inside the layout the same size?

Comment: I think... using fixed dimensions may solve this.

Comment: Scaling also applies on fixed dimensions.